# Mongo(3 shards) Driver C++: When Upsert "erro SyncClusterConnection"

Tags: c++, mongodb, qt, c++11

I have a problem running the command `upsert` in `MongoDB` when I try to connect 3 shards.

If I connect only one shard, I don't have problems.

The code I'm using is:

```
ConnectionString cs("mongodb://host:pass@server1:27017,server2:27017,server3:27017", ConnectionString::ConnectionType::SYNC);

DBClientBase *conn = cs.connect( mongo_erro );
BSONObjBuilder bojUpsert;

bojUpsert.append("teste","1234567890");
bojUpsert.append("valor",123);

conn->update("xxx.xxx", Query("{teste:\"1234567890\"}") , bojUpsert.obj() , mongo::UpdateOptions::UpdateOption_Upsert);
```

And the error I receive is:

```
 **terminate called after throwing an instance of 'mongo::UserException'
  what():  SyncClusterConnection::update upsert query needs _id**
```

**I'm using Linux Mint, QT 4.8.6 + libmongo-client-dev 0.1.7-1**

Comment: I'm confused. The libmongo-client-dev package refers to an obsoleted C language driver. The API you appear to be using is the Legacy C++ driver API. What driver are you really using? How did you obtain it (built from source, package manager, etc.).

Comment: I installed through the repository (using the aptitude).

Comment: You installed *what package* with aptitude. I'm trying to tell you that the package you named libmongo-client-dev doesn't have the symbols you seem to be using. It isn't even written in the same language. Something doesn't add up.

Comment: You also haven't shown a complete, compilable example, or indicated what version of MongoDB you are using, etc. You need to provide a *lot* more information in order to provide enough useful material for anyone to be able to help.